# Trouble in setting up a angular2 typescript environment

Tags: angular

I have been trying to set up a typescript angular2 project structure as shown in the documentation. but the problem is it fails to install typings due to timeout. i tried changing to a particular version but no luck there too. Below is the error i'm getting when i use npm install

> typings ERR! message Unable to connect to "https://api.typings.org/entries/dt/co
>   re-js/tags/0.0.0%2B20160317120654" typings ERR! caused by connect
>   ETIMEDOUT 104.24.112.177:443
>
> typings ERR! cwd
>   C:\Users\nayakb\workspace\AngularJS2\angular2-tutorial typings ERR!
>   system Windows_NT 6.1.7601 typings ERR! command "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\nayakb\w
>   orkspace\AngularJS2\angular2-tutorial\node_modules\typings\dist\bin.js"
>   "i nstall" typings ERR! node -v v5.9.1 typings ERR! typings -v 1.0.4
>   typings ERR! code EUNAVAILABLE
>
> typings ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at: typings
>   ERR!   https://github.com/typings/typings/issues
>
> npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency
>   /chokidar/fsevents: npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating
>   system or architecture: fseve nts@1.0.12 npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>   npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
>   "C:\Users\nayakb\AppData\
>   \Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" npm ERR!
>   node v5.9.1 npm ERR! npm  v3.9.2 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR!
>   angular2-seed@0.0.0 postinstall: `typings install && gulp
>   check.version s && npm prune && gulp webdriver` npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-seed@0.0.0 postinstall script
>   'typings install & & gulp check.versions && npm prune && gulp
>   webdriver'. npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js
>   and npm installed. npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem
>   with the angular2-seed package , npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm
>   ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system: npm ERR!
>   typings install && gulp check.versions && npm prune && gulp webdriv er
>   npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this
>   project with: npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-seed npm ERR! Or if that
>   isn't available, you can get their info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls
>   angular2-seed npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output
>   above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\nayakb\workspace\AngularJS2\angular2-tutorial\npm-debug.lo g

If its possible for a work around. i would love to learn about it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you get a timeout from the typings api server maybe just retry in a few minutes. I can connect to it without any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding .typingsrc file to the project root directory with the following content

```
proxy="http://proxy.company.com:8080"
rejectUnauthorized=false
```

and the rest just works fine without any trouble.

Comment: Where will be located .typingsrc file on windows?

Answer (score 1):

**ETIMEDOUT** occurs because of you not receiving any response from typings source. Now this may occur when you are behind corporate proxy. mostly `typings install` tries to download files mentioned in typings.json file which are hosted on github. if that is the case then use either of the solution:

1. you need to bypass proxy with npm config command. see [this link](https://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy).
2. Alternatively, you can place the files locally in your code
       structure. for ex for jasmine.d.ts in tsconfig folder:

   ```
       "jasmine": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts#d594ef506d1efe2fea15f8f39099d19b39436b71"
   ```

   go to above url and paste the source code in a jasmine.d.ts file created locally anywhere in your current directory and then use

   ```
   <reference path = "../../jasmine.d.ts">
   ```

   in files which give typescript compile time error.
   Using this may cause the npm to give same error again but it will remove any typescript compile time error. so launch your application even after `typings install` fail.

*Note* : use `./` if jasmine.d.ts present in same directory & `../` to jump directories.

hope this helps!

Comment: i have set the proxy but still the issue persists... Will try the step 2 and let you know the results

Comment: you need to run both these command one by one : `npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080`  and 
`npm config set https_proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080`. after setting the proxy restart the command prompt and again run application.

Comment: we need to set the proxy in a .typingsrc file in the project level directory and the file content as `proxy="http://proxy.company.com:8080" rejectUnauthorized=false` then it works perfectly. setting proxy for npm alone won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove node modules folder and Try clearing npm cache: `npm cache clear`. Then try npm install and see if it works.